# windows python Python v3.2.2 text file read no error nor output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to read a text file via win python 3, the strange thing is that I am not getting any error nor any output.

```
f = open ('C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\test.txt','r')  
data = f.read()  
print data  
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` is a function in py3

```
f = open ('C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\test.txt','r')
data = f.read()
print(data)
f.close()
```

Though, it should have give you invalid syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for the input, just tried but somehow still no output nor error.

Comment: Did you write anything to the file?

Comment: Binary/text? Also, what environment are you using?

Comment: i am running on win7-x64U-intel-i7 with standard text file.

Comment: Try to run it with print statements between the commands and to tell where it stops

Comment: just tried with print statements, from 1st line to every alternate line, it only prints 1st print statement, means having issue with open statement.

Comment: Read-protected or something?
Do you get it with all files?

Comment: Sorry, don't know what to say :/

Comment: Just did the py update to latest version and tried from command line. it's works by cmd line, and throws the error if print is not as function. but idle still exhibiting same strange behavior. @pythonm thank you for time and inputs.